# How to use string literal property of an object as a key type in the same object

Tags: typescript

For example I have some interface:

```js
interface Foo {
  bar: string;
  baz: (param: any) => void;
}
```

and an object:

```js
const test = { 
  bar: 'id', 
  baz: (param) => console.log(param.id),
};
```

How could I force TypeScript to use the `bar` value as a `key` type of `param`, without using mapped types? So I want to have something like:

```js
interface Foo<J> {
  bar: J;
  baz: (param: {[key: J]: any}) => void;
}
```

and an object:

```js
const test = { 
  bar: 'id', 
  baz: ({id}) => console.log(id), // <== here should typescript allow only the id property
};
```

I know that I could use mapped type to achieve that behavior, but that not what I want here

Comment: There's no specific type in TS corresponding to this.  You can write a generic type as you've shown, but there's no type argument inference for generic *types*, only for calling generic *functions*.  So you can make a helper function to do the inference for you, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wk3jPW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Wonderful! That exactly what I wanted! But one thing first - is it possible to achieve that with typecasting? Just curious if it is possible :)

Comment: TS doesn't really have "typecasting" so I'm not sure what you're saying.  It has *type assertions*, but I don't see how that's related to this question.  Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry - meant ofc the type assertions. My question is- would it be possible to create some assertion `asFoo` and then just call it like `asFoo<Foo>`.  So at the end I have something like `const test: asFoo<Foo> = ...;`

Comment: How is `asFoo` an "assertion"? I think there are terminology issues preventing proper communication.  I can say that there is no specific type in TypeScript `X` that will work for `const test: X = ...;`, whether or not `X` is written as `asFoo<Foo>` or not.  So I'd say the answer is no, you can't do that. Would it be okay to dispense with this hypothetical change of approach and move on so I can write up an answer post?  Or is there still something that has to be discussed first?

Comment: Yes you can move on and write the answer - thank you :)

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance.  It will probably be a few hours from now at the earliest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *specific* type `Foo` in TypeScript which works this way.  The closest you can get is to represent your requirement as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `Foo<K>` where `K` corresponds to the `bar` property.  It's very close to what you had except that you were trying to use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) `{[key: K]: any}` which isn't valid for generics.  You need a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{[P in K]: any}` instead:

```
interface Foo<K extends PropertyKey> {
  bar: K;
  baz: (param: { [P in K]: any }) => void;
}
```

And unfortunately the compiler cannot infer type arguments to generic types, so you can't write `const test: Foo<infer> = {⋯}` or `const test: Foo<?> = {⋯}` or `const test: Foo = {⋯}` or anything like that.  The compiler *can* infer type arguments when you call generic *functions*, though, so you can create a helper function:

```
const asFoo = <K extends PropertyKey>(foo: Foo<K>) => foo;
```

and then use it like `const test = asFoo({⋯})`:

```
const test = asFoo({
  bar: 'id',
  baz: ({ id }) => console.log(id), // okay
});

const test2 = asFoo({
  bar: 'id',
  baz: ({ oops }) => console.log(oops), // error 
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4DSyIAekIAJgM7IAKU6ADtGAJ44SMB8yA3gLABQyyAEZwoALmQ4A3HwHCAXuIAUtEXAC24zsgDalZKAkBdcXBCNkAXwCUyALwcAbumAlpvC3wToQZMMjhkGOh2yLj4RBCkFNR0DMysbIowmOJBuGw29sjJ6G6e3r7IkIW2-oGYijz8QiLiAOQudQA0MjUKyJX6JJaZHF4+6AA2EAB0g+gA5oouVk3IAPTzyBOYJHzWebz9hcVgAEwhAUGVrcJiyA0kzadw7Z2YtBTWdn0FQ6PjUw9kswtLwmt3FY3EA)

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, to use the bar value as a key type in the param object of the baz function without using mapped types, you can achieve this by defining the type of param with a dynamic key using indexed access types. Here's how you can do it

```
interface Foo<J extends string> {
  bar: J;
  baz: (param: { [key in J]: any }) => void;
}

const test: Foo<'id'> = {
  bar: 'id',
  baz: ({ id }) => console.log(id),
};
```

Comment: Its good start, thanks! Would be nice if you could force `Foo` to set J implicitly by setting `bar`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see an indexed access type here, where is it?  You might be using the wrong terminology.